# Redirect 301 of old urls to wordpress urls

Tags: redirect, regex

I am migrating a website from vivvo cms to wordpress. Vivvo is using category pages like index.**numberofthepage**.html

I want to redirect urls like using regex:

```
https://www.example.com/mycats/index.200.html
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/mycats/page/200/
```

mycats could be more than one category ex cat1/cat2... and the 200 could be any number. I used :

```
^/index.(.*?)\.html to ^/page/$1/
```

But not redirecting.
Thanks

Comment: Please add the context in which you are using the redirect rule.

Comment: I migrated a website from vivvo cms to wordpress. Iwould like to avoid 404 errors. Vivvo is using category pages like index.**numberpage**.html

Comment: I mean: are you using the regex in a PHP file, in an nginx config or in a .htaccess? Right now it's impossible even to guess what is wrong.

Comment: using the regex in the plugin "Redirection" [link](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since category and page number is dynamic, you can use htaccess and use this sample rewrite rule below:

```
RewriteRule (.*?)/index.(.*?)\.html $1/page/$2/
```

You can test the regex here - https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and I can see that it is working as far as I have tested it.

PS: URL Redirections are **cached aggresively**, you need to clear you browser cache completely to make sure that you are testing it properly.

Hope this helps!